# Ryzen + KVM very slow vilrtualization

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I want to switch form my old Intel platform to new Ubuntu 18.04 LTS + Ryzen 2700 + Asus X470 F Gaminng mobo. Virtualization is a must for me. So after installing clean Ubuntu I've installed KVM + QEMU.

When I run Ubuntu 16.04 just live CD in virtual machine it is painfully slow. **It turns on in about 5 minutes**.

But running Ubuntu 18.04 live CD in virtual machine works as I expect it to be - super fast.

I have enabled **IOMMU** and **SVM** in bios and command `kvm-ok` says:

```
KVM acceleration can be used
```

I've tried to change Video to different modes (QLX, VGA etc) - nothing changes.

I've tried to change emulated CPU to Broadwell, Haswell, and few other options - nothing changes.

Any suggestions where to look to resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what your'e asking me for. But kvm-info says
`INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used`

also `lscpu` shows: `Virtualization:      AMD-V`

Comment: I got into monitor and I got: `kvm support: enabled`

Comment: You could take a look if you are cpu bound and if so in which of qemu's threads that is via `pidstat -t -p <pid-of-qemu>` - the share between guest/user/sys in that would often also indicate where to look next.

Comment: Didn't get chance to check it. I've reinstalled Ubuntu and now it works properly. It's a pity that I didn't get to the core of this problem. Anyway thank you for your help.